# Wordpress roots theme installation ERROR

Tags: wordpress, node.js, gruntjs, bower, bower-install

I'm using [roots](http://roots.io/) theme for wordpress but its to much hard to install. I'm installing all of its required tools such as: Nodejs, npm, grunt-cli and bower but no luck.

At the end in my theme folder using command npm install that providing this error.

[image]

Lots of searching regarding this but nothing found to fix this.

Also when i'm using command (grunt dev) in node command prompt given error generated. I think this error depends on previous error.

[image]

Anybody here to explain where i'm wrong to use this theme. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. delete the "node_modules" folder from your theme folder
2. on your command prompt run this code "npm install clean"

http://discourse.roots.io/t/roots-makes-its-debut-at-wordcamp-lax-2014/2042/2

I hope this helps. =)

Comment: @webtuts4u - did you fix this. Having the same issue.

Comment: @daniel Not fix, I am leaving the root themes. If you fix this please post your answer here. Thanks.